# IE 9 doesn't display teaser image and summary in Drupal 7

Tags: internet-explorer, drupal, view, teaser

In all other main browsers it is perfectly ok, but in IE 9 Drupal doesn't display teaser image and summary text. In views building mode (preview) images and text is shown but on the 'live' page only title is displayed. I am using Drupal 7. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check in IE firebug whether its loading HTML or not, if yes then you need to check your CSS.